# Why are functions thread safe on a machine code level if they don't use global data?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, architecture, processor, machine-code

I've been thinking about this for a few days now: when I'm compiling a function into machine code, it's simply a distinct part of the whole code base. When I call a function the parameters get copied and the instruction pointer of the process will jump to the beginning of the function. Is that correct?

If so, I don't understand how functions can be thread safe if they don't use global data. Let's say two threads are simultaneously invoking the same function with different data. So they are both working with the same instruction data in the RAM. How is it ensured that they don't mix themselves up? Is that what the context switch is for?

I think I have some misunderstanding on how functions work on a machine code level. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full answer, but...

If you want to get all computer-science-y about it, the name of the place where the arguments and local variables of an active function call are stored is *[activation record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure)*. The "stack" that we so often talk about in most modern programming languages, is in fact, a stack *of* activation records.

I am old enough to have used languages in which function activation records were statically allocated, which meant that recursion was not possible in those languages, nor would threading have been possible if anybody had thought of threading yet. I have also heard of one programming language, [Self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_(programming_language)), in which activation records are first class objects, that are allocated from the heap.